# Can't install nodejs-legacy

Tags: node.js, debian, installation

I'm trying to follow [this](http://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) tutorial and having issues with Node.js installation. Installing on a Debian VM, and have run the suggested installation command on the nodejs site:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejson
```

When I run `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` It gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-legacy : Depends: nodejs (>= 0.6.19~dfsg1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: `Depends: nodejs (>= 0.6.19~dfsg1-3~) but it is not going to be installed.` Install recent version of node.js . It could fix the problem

Comment: Unistalled version 6 and installed version 8. No luck unfortunately

Comment: Try to change url to `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -`

Comment: 2044 views. It means that it is a common enough issue. But no solution?

Comment: Did anyone figure out the solution for this? I even tried updating node to the latest version. Still the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Found this old .txt file with some instructions whilst sorting through junk. Looks like I ended up solving the problem.

1. sudo apt-get install python3-pip
2. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -

   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

   sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
3. sudo npm i webpack -g
4. sudo npm install --global yarn@1.0.2
5. https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres
   sudo -u postgres psql -c 'create database saleor'

   sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE ROLE saleor WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'saleor';"

   sudo -u postgres psql -c 'grant all privileges on database saleor to saleor;'
6. sudo apt-get install python3-venv

   pyvenv env1

   source env1/bin/activate

   deactivate
7. sudo apt-get install git
8. git clone https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git
9. cd saleor
10. pip3 install -r requirements.txt
11. export SECRET_KEY='yourkey'
12. python3 manage.py migrate
13. yarn
14. sudo apt-get install libfontconfig
15. yarn run build-assets